# How to modify/override inherited class function in python?

Tags: python-3.x, class, inheritance, overriding

I have the exact function name `say_hello` in both parent and inherited class. I want to specify the parameter `name` in the Kitten class but allows for user to specify the parameter in Cat class.

Is there a way to avoid the needs to repeat the line `return ('Hello '+name)` in the `say_hello` function in Kitten class?

Currently:

```
class Cat:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def say_hello(name):
        return ('Hello '+name)

class Kitten(Cat):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def say_hello(name='Thomas'):
        return ('Hello '+name)

x = Cat
print (x.say_hello("Sally"))
y = Kitten
print (y.say_hello())
```

Ideally:

```
class Cat:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def say_hello(name):
        return ('Hello '+name)

class Kitten(Cat):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def say_hello():
        return super().say_hello(name='Thomas') # Something like this, so this portion of the code doesn't need to repeat completely
```

Comment: I just figured this could be done using `return Cat.say_hello(name='Thomas') `. Is this a correct way to do what I want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `say_hello` method should include `self` as the first parameter so that it can use the `super()` function to access the parent's `say_hello` method. You should also instantiate a class by calling it with parentheses:

```
class Cat:
    def say_hello(self, name):
        return 'Hello ' + name

class Kitten(Cat):
    def say_hello(self, name='Thomas'):
        return super().say_hello(name)

x = Cat()
print(x.say_hello("Sally"))
y = Kitten()
print(y.say_hello())
```

This outputs:

```
Hello Sally
Hello Thomas
```

Comment: I am trying to be aware of potential bad practices. If I don't include `self` in Kitten's `say_hello`, and `return Cat.say_hello(name='Thomas')`. This is a bad practice? Even if I don't need to use `super()` function?

Comment: The first parameter of an instance method is always the instance object itself, even if you name it something other than `self`. If the method has no need to access any instance attributes, you can avoid including `self` as the first parameter by making it a static method using the `@staticmethod` decorator instead.

Comment: What if `name` is between other arguments, such in `say_hello(self, a, b, name, c, d="d", e="e")`?

Answer (score 0):

i think you might miss a point about classes here which is crucial to what you want to achieve.

Let's first define a class `Cat` but take a close look at the differences to yours.

```
class Cat:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def say_hello(self):
        return self.name
```

And now see the magic and i explain it later :

```
cat = Cat("Sally")
print(cat.say_hello())
>>> "Sally"
```

What happened in comparison to your code ?

First, your `__init__` method does not take an argument. My version does and it is `name`. Furthermore i asign it to an instance variable `self.name` .
With this asignment i can access the name provided at instantiation in EVERY method which has `self` as it's first argument. What is instantiation ?
Well in your code you called `x = Cat`. With this x is an object of the class but not an Instance. You need to instantiate your class.

By doing so in my code `cat = Cat("Sally")` what python does is call the `__init__` method of the class and return an Instance of it with everythin set/done as specified in the `__init__`method.

In my case i set `self.name = name` which makes , in the example, the value of `self.name` to "Sally".

So whenever i call `self.name` in a method , which includes `self` in it's parameters it becomes, after instantiation, "Sally".

Now the class `Cat` should be clear.

What to do now ?

Simply inherit from this class !

See:

```
class Cat:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def say_hello(self):
        return self.name


class Kitten(Cat):
    def __init__(self, name):
        # This is done for convenience
        super().__init__(name)
```

With this a Kitten-, same as a Cat-instance has a name and inherits the `say_hello()` mehtod to say it's name .

I hope this helps.

Comment: This example code simplifies the larger/complex code I am trying to construct. I see why you made that suggestion based on my example, the name of a cat should be considered as an attribute, but my focus is really about function and its parameters that overlap in both parent and inherited classes, cat and name are merely placeholders to illustrate where I am trying to work on. But thank you!